# How to make the progress bar increase when i swipe the cards

Tags: swift, xcode, swipe

I have a progressbar in my app and below that i am displaying the cards from mdel array which are swipeable like tinder app. So when i swipe first card, the progresbar should increase according to it, then for second card, it should increase and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you that you mentioned you're using ZLSwipeableViewSwift, in your didEnd callback, set the progress bars value to the count of the view shown of your model array.

```
swipeableView.didEnd = {view, location in
    self.progressViewBar.progress = 1.0 * Float(self.swipeableView.numberOfActiveView) / Float(self.wordsData.count)
    print("Did end swiping view at location: \(location)")
}
```

Comment: No i am using uiview as subclass to display cards, i have used ZLSwipeable library

Comment: Edited my answer, would have helped to mention that library from the beginning.

Comment: i have written like this self.progressViewBar.progress = self.progressViewBar.progress * Float(self.swipeableView.numberOfActiveView / UInt(self.wordsData.count)), but it doesnt works

Comment: have progressViewBar as an outlet

Comment: in your answer, progressBar.value = progressBar.maximumValue * swipeableView.numberOfActiveView / modelArray.count, progressbar.value and progressbar.maximumvalue doesnt show up

Comment: i have managed to increase progressbar for one card but when i swipe another the progressbar doesnt increase. My code in swipe.didend is:  self.progressViewBar.progress = 1.0 / Float(UInt(self.wordsData.count))

Comment: You have the multiple the progress bar's maximum value, which is 1.0, by the value of the current card divided by the total number of cards.  I did that in my previous edit where it said 'progressBar.maximumValue'.  I can't give you the exact answer without seeing your code and not very often will you get the exact answer to your problem when seeking help.  Try to use example code to understand what is going on and how it solves the problem, then apply how that to your own code.  My current edit should be closer to working for you, you may need to edit it to suit your needs as I can't test it.

Comment: I have raised another problem regarding ZLSwipeable view library of how to flip the card to reveal back side